# Maximum prime divisor of $13^4+16^5-172^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My approach:

I tried it by remainder theorem as there 13,16 which are very close and raised to the power some small powers. 
So if it becomes like :

$$13^4+(13+3)^5-(13*13+3)²$$

Now how should I proceed,  $13$ will obviously not be the answer.

Comment: Note that $3^5-3^2 = 9(3^3-1)=9*26$. So $13^4 +16^5 - 172^2 \equiv 0 $ (mod 13) so you at least have a 13 in there. One possible tactic then is to expand out the (13+3)^5 and (13*13+3)^2 using Pascal's triangle and then look at what the resulting number after you have divided by 13 looks like. That should be substantially smaller and may be easier to factor.